# How to use JWT Refresh Token?

Tags: jwt

I want to implement JWT authentication for my REST APIs.
The client is a Reactjs web app and the backend is Expressjs REST API.

Assume this scenario,

1. User accesses /login route, the server generates an access-token & a refresh-token and sends them to the client. Where do I store the access-token & refresh-token? Do I also store the refresh-token on my DB along with particular userID?
2. The access-token has reached its expiry. How do I refresh it without having to make the user log in again with credentials?

Does the client need to know about the refresh-token? When it tries to access a route with an expired access-token, the server could just verify it and use the refresh-token associated with the userID from the DB and generate a new access-token for the client.

Comment: You need to specify a lot more about your application for better answers but in general it is best practice to only keep tokens in the parts of the application that absolutely needs them.  If you have a stateful backend which can handle your jwt transactions for you, only keep your tokens there and never share in a way that the client application can read them.  I keep my access tokens only in memory if I can afford it. Storing refresh tokens in a (locked down, possibly encrypted) database is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Following assumes OAuth 2.0 / OpenId Connect.

1. Best place IMO for access tokens is in memory. Refresh tokens for native apps should be stored securely on the device. Note: you shouldn't be storing refresh tokens in web clients / browsers. Native apps can receive a refresh token by specifying `offline_access` in the list of scopes specified on the request to the `/token` endpoint.
2. For native apps that have received a refresh token, you could detect 401 responses from requests to protected routes and subsequently attempt to obtain a new access token from the refresh token (stored securely on the device). To get a new access token using the refresh token, you can make another request to the `/token` endpoint, but this time specifying `grant_type=refresh_token` in addition to the actual refresh token e.g. see example request below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=4d7481b6-9de3-4e20-9fc1-f907cda9d993&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&refresh_token=QWERTY123&scope=openid%20offline_access" https://idp.example.com/token
```

One last thing; unless you can tightly manage access to your database, for security reasons you probably shouldn't consider storing refresh tokens in the db.